# Android - View added during drag is not registered as drop target

Tags: android, listview, scroll, drag-and-drop, xamarin.android

I have a ListView that is filled with contacts. When a user starts to drag a shareable item, this list appears. To highlight the currently selected contact I animate the profile picture in the drag event.

When I move the drag shadow to the bottom the list scrolls down using a custom defined method. I call `NotifyDataSetChanged` afterwards. This works for scrolling and all contacts are shown fine, but after I scroll no drag events are received on the contacts anymore (so no animations are being shown, plus I don't know when the user actually drops the item).

I read somewhere that this is because they are not registered as drop targets. So, my question is, how do I register them?

Using Xamarin.Android BTW, but I don't think that changes anything, Java answers are welcome too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

A workaround exists, setting items newly scrolled into view to `Visibility.Invisible` and then back to `Visible` registers them as a drop target.

I created a custom ListView that scrolls automatically when a user is currently dragging something and also registers items that come into view.
See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/PiMaker/0d1572aa532ca67c39259dc5e33aac83).

Working flawlessly!